# Show that there exist $x\in X$ such that $x\notin\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a compact Hausdorff topological space. Let $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}}$ a collection of countable closed, such that the interior of $A_{n}$ is empty, for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Show that, there exist  $x\in X$ such that $x\notin\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$.

So, I know this union has empty interior, [Prob. 5, Sec. 27 in Munkres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296634/prob-5-sec-27-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-every-compact-hausdorff-space-is). But, if the interior of the union is empty, maybe there exist a point in the boundary of $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$.

Can give me some hint, or any idea to prove this, pls. Thanks!

Comment: If the interior of the union is empty, any neighbourhood of a point in the union contains a suitable $x$.

Comment: To say there is no such $x$ is to say $X = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Does $X$ have empty interior?

Comment: What do you refer with a suitable $x$???, Thanks for your answer! @RobertIsrael

Comment: I mean an $x$ that is not in $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

Comment: why would a point in the boundary be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Compact Hausdorff space is a Baire space.
And any non-empty open set in a baire space is of the second category, that is it cannot be written as countable union of nowhere dense sets.

The sets $A_n$ are all nowhere dense as they are closed and has an empty interior, and since $X$ is open in itself so $X\neq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$, hence there exists $x\in X$ such that $x\notin\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see why $X\neq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$... Thanks!

Comment: Because $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is a countable union of nowhere dense subsets.

Comment: Nice and concise :D

Comment: Thanks! @Arpan1729

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Robert Israel's comment:  let $x\in X$ be such that $x \not\in \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. Then there exists an open ball $B(x,r)$ of some positive radius $r>0$ centred at $x$ (because $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space) and so we claim that $B(x,r)\not\subset \left( \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \right)$.  Suppose the ball *were* contained in the union: then by the definition of *interior* the ball would be contained in that (because it's an open set) -- but we know that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ has empty interior.
Since $B(x,r)\not\subset \left( \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \right)$ there exists some $p\in B(x,r)\in X$ with $p\not\in \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$, which is what you wanted to show.

There is an extra point for completeness: if $X=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ then our assumption we can find an $x$ not in the union doesn't hold -- but then as Arpan1729 says $X$ would not be compact Hausdorff at that point, so we don't need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

$X \setminus A_n$ is dense as $\overline{X \setminus A_n} = X\setminus \operatorname{Int}(A_n) = X$, and open as the $A_n$ are closed. 
So $$\bigcap_n (X \setminus A_n) = X \setminus (\bigcup_n A_n)$$ is dense by Baire's theorem, so $\bigcup_n A_n \neq X$. (the empty set is not dense as $X \neq \emptyset$; we can even say $\operatorname{Int}(\bigcup_n A_n) = \emptyset$, or this interior would be a non-empty open set disjoint from the dense set.

Comment: Nitpicking: Where does it say that X is not empty?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet the stament is false for empty $X$, true for non-empty $X$. So it should be assumed anyway. Some texts explicitly demand all spaces be non-empty (OK, you don't get an initial object in Top, or the discrete adjunction from Set to Top does not quite work), but assuming all spaces are non-empty is quite convenient...

Comment: @Arpan1729 in any space $X$ the whole space is its own interior by definition. So non-empty if $X$ is.

Comment: How did you say  $\cup_n A_n$ has empty interior directly?

Comment: @Arpan1729 because the complements of the $A_n$ are open and dense, so their intersection is dense. Now apply de Morgan.